# SFINAE-based detection using void_t and protected nest classes

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, detection, void-t

I encountered some divergent behavior between clang and gcc recently regarding `void_t` property detection and protected/private class information. Consider a type trait defined as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename = void>
constexpr const bool has_nested_type_v = false;

template<typename T>
constexpr const bool has_nested_type_v
<T, std::void_t<typename T::type>> = true;
```

Given example types with protected or private nested `type` classes and a simple program

```
#include "has_nested_type.hpp"
#include <iostream>

struct Protected {
protected:
  struct type{};
};

struct Private {
private:
  struct type{};
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "Protected: " 
            << (has_nested_type_v<Protected> ? "detected" : "not detected")
            << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Private: " 
            << (has_nested_type_v<Private> ? "detected" : "not detected")
            << std::endl;
}
```

- clang compiles successfully with a failed detection (as expected). The program, compilation, and output are reproduced on wandbox [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ENMf0ALIn3sjv08f).
- gcc fails to compile, issuing a diagnostic. This error can be reproduced on wandbox [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/obPvrp3921kG7Q95).

GCC issues the following error for this program.

```
prog.cc:16:21: error: 'struct Protected::type' is protected within this context
                 << (has_nested_type_v<Protected> ? "detected" : "not detected")
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:6:14: note: declared protected here
       struct type{};
              ^~~~
prog.cc:19:21: error: 'struct Private::type' is private within this context
                 << (has_nested_type_v<Private> ? "detected" : "not detected")
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:11:14: note: declared private here
       struct type{};
              ^~~~
```

My question is which behavior is standard conformant? Should clang error here and issue a diagnostic or is GCC being overly eager?

Comment: MSVC gives the same results as Clang, FWIW (tested with VS 2017).

Comment: icc also compiles it: https://godbolt.org/z/xuVKjU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79163). It's a part of the [following meta-bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59002) that describes several access-related bugs.

Comment: Oof. Outstanding since 2013. That's really a shame.